# Collison behaviour boundries not respected

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, collision-detection

Presenting a `UIView` from under the nav bar with "bounce effect" `self.dropDownBar`

Despite setting up boundaries the `UIView` continues to drop off the bottom of the screen

Checked here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollisionBehavior_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollisionBehavior/addBoundaryWithIdentifier:fromPoint:toPoint:

That states:

addBoundaryWithIdentifier:fromPoint:toPoint:
p1
The starting point for the boundary line segment.
p2
The ending point for the boundary line segment.  Seem to be doing that,

and here [Collision not working between items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769593/collision-not-working-between-items) (no accepted answer and nothing suitable)

```
.h
<UICollisionBehaviorDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIDynamicAnimator *animator;


.m
self.animator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self.view];

    UIGravityBehavior* gravityBehavior =
    [[UIGravityBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[self.dropDownBar]];
    [self.animator addBehavior:gravityBehavior];

    UICollisionBehavior* collisionBehavior =
    [[UICollisionBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[self.dropDownBar]];



    //To - from boundries
    [collisionBehavior addBoundaryWithIdentifier:@"NotificationBoundary" fromPoint:CGPointMake(0, 45)
                                                                         toPoint:CGPointMake(0, 90)];

    [self.animator addBehavior:collisionBehavior];
```

What am I missing here?